# Oracle Button issue

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

Working on a oracle project. I am new to oracle forms. I am currently using 10g forms. I am successfully able to develop my first form from datablock wizard. It initially contained 10 rows. After that i tried to make a button but 10 buttons show up. All have same name and behave like a single unit but they look like 10 buttons.

http://postimage.org/image/breymi2pn/

Following is the image of buttons which i am getting on form canvas:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the multiple buttons is that you have added the button to a multi record block. You can fix this problem either by moving the button to a single record control block. If you need to have the button in the multi record block but only want to display one button then you need to set the 'Number of Items displayed' item level property for the button item to 1.

[image: Item property Number of Items Displayed]